# Is this also the variation or extension of Continuous mapping theorem?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, measure-theory

The common CMT (continuous mapping theorem) claim that: If $X_n \overset{p}{\rightarrow} X$, and $g$ is some continuous function, then
\begin{align}
g(X_n) \overset{p}{\rightarrow} g(X)
\end{align}

However, when I read an article, I saw the following application of CMT:

Suppose $\{X_n\}$ is a sequence of random variables, $\{c_n \}$ is a sequence of real numbers, without randomness. If $X_n - c_n \overset{p}{\rightarrow} 0$, then by CMT, we know that: $g(X_n) - g(c_n) \overset{p}{\rightarrow} 0$.

I think I never met this version of CMT before, though I feel the above claim maybe right. Could anyone give a reference(some textbook is better) or hint on how to show this claim?

Comment: Why are the constants indexed by ${}_{n}$ if they're, you know, _constant_?

Comment: Sorry, that's my bad, it's a sequence of real numbers, I use constant to mean that {cn} without any randomness. Let me fix that description.

Answer (score 3):

A useful question to ask is whether the answer would be easy if the convergence was almost sure (or deterministic). It would. So try subsequences or almost sure representations.

$X_n-c_n\stackrel{p}{\to}0$ is true iff for every subsequence $n_i$ there is a subsubsequence $n_{i_j}$ with $X_{n_{i_j}}-c_{n_{i_j}}\stackrel{a.s}{\to}0$.
If $g$ is a continuous function, this implies $g(X_{n_{i_j}})-g(c_{n_{i_j}})\stackrel{a.s}{\to}0$ for the subsubsequence just as a fact about continuity: continuous transformation preserves convergence. But that implies $g(X_{n})-g(c_{n})\stackrel{p}{\to}0$